# Unique characters from a column of concatenated strings

Tags: r, string

I have a data.frame with a string column 'city' which consists of concatenated letters separated by `;`

```
dt = data.frame(id = letters[1:6],
                city = c("A;B","B;D","A;D;G","A;C","F;G","C;D"))
dt
#   id    city
# 1  a     A;B
# 2  b     B;D
# 3  c   A;D;G
# 4  d     A;C
# 5  e     F;G
# 6  f     C;D`
```

I hope to get the unique individual letters from the 'city' column:

```
city = c("A","B","C","D","F","G")`
```

How to do this?

Comment: how does c appear in row 3?

Comment: What's the criteria used to get the desired output?

Comment: The data you create and the data you show as dt are not the same

Comment: I just want to get a variable city which contains the unique value of dt$city.

Comment: I am sorry. I have edited the codes again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cleaner solution would be:

```
dt= data.frame(id=letters[1:6],city = c("A;B","B;D","A;D;G","A;C","F;G","C;D"))

city=strsplit(as.character(dt$city), ";")

city=sort(unique(unlist(city)))

[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "F" "G"
```

Comment: Oh, I did not know that `strsplit` is vectorized. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

The data:

```
dt=  data.frame(id=letters[1:6],city = c("A;B","B;D","A;D;G","A;C","F;G","C;D"))

> dt
  id  city
1  a   A;B
2  b   B;D
3  c A;D;G
4  d   A;C
5  e   F;G
6  f   C;D
```

Split the column `city`, using `as.character` to convert to strings:

```
city <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(dt$city), ";", fixed = T))

> city
 [1] "A" "B" "B" "D" "A" "D" "G" "A" "C" "F" "G" "C" "D"
```

Now use `unique` and `order` to get the output:

```
city <- unique(city)

> city
[1] "A" "B" "D" "G" "C" "F"

city <- city[order(city)]

> city
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "F" "G"

> dput(city)
c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "G")
```

---

Edit: Updated with OPs new data.

Edit2: Updated to omit the `sapply`, as apparently `strsplit` is vectorized. Thanks @Cris!

Comment: The desired output doesn't match yours. We were asking how to get there in the comments of the original question. It can be a misspell from OP, but I think this doesn't answer the question itself.

Comment: OP provided corrected data, the expected output now fits OPs wishes. Why do you think my solution doesn't answer OPs question?